# Is there a way to convert date to epoch prior to Perl 5.8?

Tags: regex, linux, perl

Is there a way to convert from date to epoch in Perl **5.8.8**?

I know that there is `DateTime` module but it is not supported in **5.8.8**

Comment: you are mistaken: DateTime supports perl 5.8.1 or greater.

Comment: Time::Local has been a part of the standard Perl library since 5.00 in 1994.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does this date you want to convert look like?

Time::Local::timegm or Time::Local::timelocal or POSIX::mktime can all assemble year, month, day, hour, minute, second into an epoch time.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with the [`Time::Local`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Local.html) module which is a core module.

```
use Time::Local;
my $time = timelocal($sec,$min,$hours,$day,$month,$year);
```

If your date is either `GMT` or `UTC` you can simply replace (`timelocal`) with (`timegm`)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $time = time;
print $time
```

OR

```
use Date::Parse;
print str2time("02/25/2011 11:50AM");
```

OR

```
use POSIX;
$now_string = strftime "%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Y", localtime;
# or for GMT formatted appropriately for your locale:
$now_string = strftime "%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Y", gmtime;
print str2time($now_string);
```

References:
http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html
http://www.epochconverter.com/programming/functions-perl.php